# Meaning of "AS FOR" expression

Tags: meaning, expressions

What is the meaning of the expression "as for others" in the sentence bellow:

> God does not have such a love for them
>   **as for others**

Comment: There's also a Q&A at ell.stackexchange.com for learners.

Answer (score 5):

It is making a comparison. You can expand the sentence so:

> God does not have such a love for them
>   as [He has] for others.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an expression "as for others" in that sentence. "As" is part of the coordinate structure "such ... as", while "for" in "for others" parallels "for them".